# Sort by unique name and latest date

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, group-by, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to sort a table to show on a datastudio report, the problem I have is that I need to sort out values by Name and By the latest date, this is to keep track of a servicing regime, I want to create a report that shows only the name of the latest service done on the "bike" to ignore older services for same customers. I kinda made it work but it still shows duplicate names and I cannot work around it :(

Then after I have that how would I have another sheet that shows the upcoming services next week (we service every 8 weeks)

Hope I make sense. I am using Google Sheets and here is the [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-SfhGqLIs3Z-E9PAFZHmM9wPdF1SAlqHdDErTHFd8Ww/edit?usp=sharing) to the sheet

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see:

```
=SORTN(SORT(B2:E, 1, ), 9^9, 2, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! that works really well, can you explain me the last part of the formula? If it is not much trouble!

Comment: @Champoleon sure. first, we sort `B2:E` by dates `1` in descending `0` order then we use sortn to: output all possible rows `9^9` while we use second `2` mode of sortn to group data by second `2` column ordered in ascending `1` manner